# SSRS Change background colour of cell in a expanding matrix

Tags: sql, matrix, reporting-services

I have a matrix table that looks like this:

[image]

```
="£" & FormatNumber(Sum(Fields!CalculatedFee.Value * 
        Fields!Unit.Value), 2, False, False, True)
```

When the report is run, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it populates this year's and the previous year's data, the year is a group also.

What I would like to achieve is to colour the cell of this year's net when it is lower than the previous.

For example:

[image]

I have tried many many ways to make this work but I'm stuck. My latest incarnation is this, which fails:

```
=IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Year(now) and Sum(Fields!CalculatedFee.Value * 
        Fields!Unit.Value) < IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Year(now)-1 and 
        Sum(Fields!CalculatedFee.Value * Fields!Unit.Value), true, false) , 
        "Red", "")
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: I am guessing you have one row that has the 2014 data, and one row that has 2013 data, and you use the matrix report to format this.

What you might need to do is design a sql query, so on a single row you have the 2014 data, with a column containing some data from a year ago. That way you can do a conditional formatting by just comparing two columns of the same row.

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for the response.  I have thought about that  but that will be my last resort option. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** 
Try something like this.

```
=IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Year(now) 
      and 
          SUM(iif(Fields!Year.Value = Year(now), Fields!CalculatedFee.Value * Fields!Unit.Value, 0.0), "YourDataSetName" )
           < SUM(iif(Fields!Year.Value = Year(now)-1, Fields!CalculatedFee.Value * Fields!Unit.Value, 0.0), "YourDataSetName" )
        ,"Red", Nothing)
```

If you specify `SUM(Fields!CalculatedFee.Value * Fields!Unit.Value)` SSRS will sum it up in your current dataset scope.

**Method 2:**
It depends on how your dataset is laid out. You may be able to use [lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function.

```
=IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Year(now) 
      and 
      Lookup(Year(now), Fields!Year.Value, Fields!CalculatedFee.Value * Fields!Unit.Value, "YourDataSetName" )
      < Lookup(Year(now)-1, Fields!Year.Value, Fields!CalculatedFee.Value * Fields!Unit.Value, "YourDataSetName" )
        ,"Red", Nothing)
```

**Method 3:**
If you can change the report output to show 2013 first and 2014 next. In that case you can use [**Previous**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255200%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function to set the color.

**Method 4:**
You can **change** the dataset **query** to set a **flag** for color. In other words do your compaision in the query and use the flag to set the color in report.